# Put the personal data to the left and remove my name at the bottom

Tags: moderncv

I would like to know, I'm a bit desperate, how to move my top personal data to the left, and remove my name at the bottom?

```
    \documentclass[11pt,a4paper,roman]{moderncv}

\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\moderncvstyle{classic} 
\moderncvcolor{green}
\nopagenumbers{}
\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\name{\Large {Michel}}{\Large {Dupont}}
\title{Resumé title}
\address{1, Rue de France}{Paris — 75000}{France}
\phone[mobile]{06 11 11 11 11} 
\email{michel.dupont@dupontmichel.com} 

\begin{document}
\recipient{Destinatario}{Departamento, Empresa}
\date{le \today}
\opening{Estimado Destinatario,}
\raggedleft{
\closing{Muchas gracias por su tiempo e interés y reciba un cordial saludo.}
\enclosure[Adjunto]{CV}
\makelettertitle

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque ultrices ultricies sapien et vehicula. Sed ut quam mattis, dignissim augue et, volutpat libero. Nulla facilisi. Nulla facilisi. Suspendisse eu libero ac mi tincidunt ullamcorper eu id risus. Maecenas dignissim tortor ac tellus tristique, et hendrerit risus finibus. Morbi rhoncus, ex in placerat lacinia, justo tortor posuere ipsum, ac scelerisque urna lectus porttitor quam. Quisque quis neque massa. Aenean metus ante, lacinia vitae eros ut, porta ullamcorper mi. Sed varius bibendum interdum. Aenean at ligula iaculis nulla egestas tristique sit amet eget eros. Nam tincidunt tempor neque a sollicitudin. Integer risus sapien, tempor vel congue eget, mattis sed mi. Nullam condimentum imperdiet pulvinar.

Nam in mi sagittis, rhoncus nisl id, elementum tortor. Pellentesque id risus laoreet mi ullamcorper gravida. Nunc eget orci vitae eros efficitur consectetur a porttitor urna. Suspendisse dapibus sapien ac nulla tincidunt fermentum. Suspendisse eleifend iaculis ex et porta. Morbi at dignissim velit. Nunc non lacus ut arcu luctus dapibus. Nulla facilisis vehicula ligula non malesuada. Sed fermentum placerat mi eu finibus. Morbi nulla velit, volutpat quis efficitur in, vestibulum sed odio. In tempus, quam quis bibendum iaculis, nulla mauris rutrum leo, pellentesque molestie est lacus ut neque. Integer luctus elementum ipsum sed molestie. Vestibulum non rutrum enim. Nulla iaculis finibus elementum. Phasellus faucibus ante et pretium semper.

Morbi volutpat in ligula ut blandit. Vivamus et arcu venenatis, faucibus ante nec, suscipit dolor. Duis id molestie sapien, nec dictum ante. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut at ante sem. Ut porttitor, tortor at convallis convallis, neque mi convallis ipsum, vel ultrices enim dolor sed diam. In dictum vulputate massa id molestie. Donec sollicitudin nisi vestibulum diam varius aliquet.

\vspace{0.6cm}


\makeletterclosing


\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]

Comment: If you like my answer and it was helpful, please consider [upvoting](http://tex.stackexchange.com/privileges/vote-up) (by clicking on the arrows next to the score) and/or marking it as the [accepted answer](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852) (by clicking on the checkmark ✓). That is the way here to say "Thank you for your help!"

Answer (score 2):

**Step One:**

[image: Changed personal data to the left]

To change in class `moderncv` the position of the data of the sender you have to find the part, where it is defined. You will find a `minipage`, where we can use environment `flushleft` (line 3 and 14 in the following code) to get the personal data to the left side. With `\hfill` (see line 5) we can move the name to the right side. See that the original minipage was only half of the text width long, I changed to total text width (line 2).

The important part of the code I changed (marked with `<=========`) is:

```
  % sender contact info
  \begin{minipage}{\textwidth}% <=======================================
    \begin{flushleft}% <================================================
    \addressfont\textcolor{color2}{%
      {\hfill\bfseries\upshape\@firstname~\@lastname}\@firstdetailselementfalse% <============
      \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@addressstreet}}{}{\makenewline\addresssymbol\@addressstreet%
        \ifthenelse{\equal{\@addresscity}{}}{}{\makenewline\@addresscity}% if \addresstreet is defined, \addresscity and addresscountry will always be defined but could be empty
        \ifthenelse{\equal{\@addresscountry}{}}{}{\makenewline\@addresscountry}}%
      \collectionloop{phones}{% the key holds the phone type (=symbol command prefix), the item holds the number
        \makenewline\csname\collectionloopkey phonesymbol\endcsname\collectionloopitem}%
      \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@email}}{}{\makenewline\emailsymbol\emaillink{\@email}}%
      \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@homepage}}{}{\makenewline\homepagesymbol\httplink{\@homepage}}%
      \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@extrainfo}}{}{\makenewline\@extrainfo}}%
      \end{flushleft}% <================================================
    \end{minipage}\\[1em]
```

To be able to change the code used in moderncv we just **copy** the part out of moderncv and insert it after loading the last package in our code. Then we can do the changes showed above.

The complete, compiling MWE with your wanted result (the changed lines are marked with `< =========`; the added code from `moderncv` you will find between the two commands `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` we need to use `@` as letter in the commands):

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,roman]{moderncv}

\usepackage[french]{babel} % error french
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\moderncvstyle{classic} 
\moderncvcolor{green}
\nopagenumbers{}
\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\makelettertitle}{%
  % recompute lengths (in case we are switching from letter to resume, or vice versa)
  \recomputeletterlengths%
  % sender contact info
  \begin{minipage}{\textwidth}% <=======================================
    \begin{flushleft}% <================================================
    \addressfont\textcolor{color2}{%
      {\hfill\bfseries\upshape\@firstname~\@lastname}\@firstdetailselementfalse% <============
      \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@addressstreet}}{}{\makenewline\addresssymbol\@addressstreet%
        \ifthenelse{\equal{\@addresscity}{}}{}{\makenewline\@addresscity}% if \addresstreet is defined, \addresscity and addresscountry will always be defined but could be empty
        \ifthenelse{\equal{\@addresscountry}{}}{}{\makenewline\@addresscountry}}%
      \collectionloop{phones}{% the key holds the phone type (=symbol command prefix), the item holds the number
        \makenewline\csname\collectionloopkey phonesymbol\endcsname\collectionloopitem}%
      \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@email}}{}{\makenewline\emailsymbol\emaillink{\@email}}%
      \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@homepage}}{}{\makenewline\homepagesymbol\httplink{\@homepage}}%
      \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@extrainfo}}{}{\makenewline\@extrainfo}}%
      \end{flushleft}% <================================================
    \end{minipage}\\[1em]
  % recipient block
  \begin{minipage}[t]{.5\textwidth}
    \raggedright%
    \addressfont%
    {\bfseries\upshape\@recipientname}\\%
    \@recipientaddress%
  \end{minipage}
  % date
  \hfill% US style
%  \\[1em]% UK style
  \@date\\[2em]% US informal style: "January 1, 1900"; UK formal style: "01/01/1900"
  % opening
  \raggedright%
  \@opening\\[1.5em]%
  % ensure no extra spacing after \makelettertitle due to a possible blank line
%  \ignorespacesafterend% not working
  \hspace{0pt}\par\vspace{-\baselineskip}\vspace{-\parskip}}

\renewcommand*{\makeletterclosing}{
  \@closing\\[3em]%
  \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@enclosure}}{}{%
    \vfill%
    {\color{color2}\itshape\enclname: \@enclosure}}}
\makeatother

\name{\Large {Michel}}{\Large {Dupont}}
\title{Resumé title}
\address{1, Rue de France}{Paris — 75000}{France}
\phone[mobile]{06 11 11 11 11} 
\email{michel.dupont@dupontmichel.com} 

\begin{document}
\recipient{Destinatario}{Departamento, Empresa}
\date{le \today}
\opening{Estimado Destinatario,}
\raggedleft{
\closing{Muchas gracias por su tiempo e interés y reciba un cordial saludo.}
\enclosure[Adjunto]{CV}
\makelettertitle

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque ultrices ultricies sapien et vehicula. Sed ut quam mattis, dignissim augue et, volutpat libero. Nulla facilisi. Nulla facilisi. Suspendisse eu libero ac mi tincidunt ullamcorper eu id risus. Maecenas dignissim tortor ac tellus tristique, et hendrerit risus finibus. Morbi rhoncus, ex in placerat lacinia, justo tortor posuere ipsum, ac scelerisque urna lectus porttitor quam. Quisque quis neque massa. Aenean metus ante, lacinia vitae eros ut, porta ullamcorper mi. Sed varius bibendum interdum. Aenean at ligula iaculis nulla egestas tristique sit amet eget eros. Nam tincidunt tempor neque a sollicitudin. Integer risus sapien, tempor vel congue eget, mattis sed mi. Nullam condimentum imperdiet pulvinar.

Nam in mi sagittis, rhoncus nisl id, elementum tortor. Pellentesque id risus laoreet mi ullamcorper gravida. Nunc eget orci vitae eros efficitur consectetur a porttitor urna. Suspendisse dapibus sapien ac nulla tincidunt fermentum. Suspendisse eleifend iaculis ex et porta. Morbi at dignissim velit. Nunc non lacus ut arcu luctus dapibus. Nulla facilisis vehicula ligula non malesuada. Sed fermentum placerat mi eu finibus. Morbi nulla velit, volutpat quis efficitur in, vestibulum sed odio. In tempus, quam quis bibendum iaculis, nulla mauris rutrum leo, pellentesque molestie est lacus ut neque. Integer luctus elementum ipsum sed molestie. Vestibulum non rutrum enim. Nulla iaculis finibus elementum. Phasellus faucibus ante et pretium semper.

Morbi volutpat in ligula ut blandit. Vivamus et arcu venenatis, faucibus ante nec, suscipit dolor. Duis id molestie sapien, nec dictum ante. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut at ante sem. Ut porttitor, tortor at convallis convallis, neque mi convallis ipsum, vel ultrices enim dolor sed diam. In dictum vulputate massa id molestie. Donec sollicitudin nisi vestibulum diam varius aliquet.

\vspace{0.6cm}


\makeletterclosing


\end{document}
```

The result you saw at the beginning of this answer.

**Step Two:**

To get the name at the bottom of the part of sender we have to change the important part a little bit more. See please this code:

```
  % sender contact info
  \begin{minipage}{\textwidth}% <=======================================
    \begin{flushleft}% <================================================
    \addressfont\textcolor{color2}{%
      \@firstdetailselementfalse% <==========deleted name first line here
      \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@addressstreet}}{}{\makenewline\addresssymbol\@addressstreet%
        \ifthenelse{\equal{\@addresscity}{}}{}{\makenewline\@addresscity}% if \addresstreet is defined, \addresscity and addresscountry will always be defined but could be empty
        \ifthenelse{\equal{\@addresscountry}{}}{}{\makenewline\@addresscountry}}%
      \collectionloop{phones}{% the key holds the phone type (=symbol command prefix), the item holds the number
        \makenewline\csname\collectionloopkey phonesymbol\endcsname\collectionloopitem}%
      \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@email}}{}{\makenewline\emailsymbol\emaillink{\@email}}%
      \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@homepage}}{}{\makenewline\homepagesymbol\httplink{\@homepage}}%
      \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@extrainfo}}{}{\makenewline\@extrainfo}%
      \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@firstname}}{}{\makenewline\hfill\bfseries\upshape\@firstname~\@lastname}}% <===== added name last line    
      \end{flushleft}% <================================================
    \end{minipage}\\[1em]
```

In the third last line I added

```
\ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@firstname}}{}{\makenewline\hfill\bfseries\upshape\@firstname~\@lastname}}%
```

to check if `@firstname`is not empty (of course it is not) to make a new line `\makenewline` add added the name as I did before. Of course I deleted the code for the name in the first line. I'm sure you find the difference by comparing this code with the first shown.  Now please change lines 15 until 30 with the code above, compile and voila, what you want:

[image: now name at the bottom]

Answer (score 0):

Add this code after loading the packages (by the way, why do you load `etoolbox`? And why do you load `lipsum` if you put dummy text in the MWE?):

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\makelettertitle}{%
  % recompute lengths (in case we are switching from letter to resume, or vice versa)
  \recomputeletterlengths%
  % sender contact info
  \begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}%
    \raggedright%
    \addressfont\textcolor{color2}{%
      {\bfseries\upshape\@firstname~\@lastname}\@firstdetailselementfalse%
      \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@addressstreet}}{}{\makenewline\addresssymbol\@addressstreet%
        \ifthenelse{\equal{\@addresscity}{}}{}{\makenewline\@addresscity}% if \addresstreet is defined, \addresscity and addresscountry will always be defined but could be empty
        \ifthenelse{\equal{\@addresscountry}{}}{}{\makenewline\@addresscountry}}%
      \collectionloop{phones}{% the key holds the phone type (=symbol command prefix), the item holds the number
        \makenewline\csname\collectionloopkey phonesymbol\endcsname\collectionloopitem}%
      \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@email}}{}{\makenewline\emailsymbol\emaillink{\@email}}%
      \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@homepage}}{}{\makenewline\homepagesymbol\httplink{\@homepage}}%
      \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@extrainfo}}{}{\makenewline\@extrainfo}}%
    \end{minipage}\\[1em]
  % recipient block
  \begin{minipage}[t]{.5\textwidth}
    \raggedright%
    \addressfont%
    {\bfseries\upshape\@recipientname}\\%
    \@recipientaddress%
  \end{minipage}
  % date
  \hfill% US style
%  \\[1em]% UK style
  \@date\\[2em]% US informal style: "January 1, 1900"; UK formal style: "01/01/1900"
  % opening
  \raggedright%
  \@opening\\[1.5em]%
  % ensure no extra spacing after \makelettertitle due to a possible blank line
%  \ignorespacesafterend% not working
  \hspace{0pt}\par\vspace{-\baselineskip}\vspace{-\parskip}}

\renewcommand*{\makeletterclosing}{
  \@closing\\[3em]%
  \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@enclosure}}{}{%
    \vfill%
    {\color{color2}\itshape\enclname: \@enclosure}}}
\makeatother
```

Basically, I took the code from `moderncvclassic.sty` and removed an `\hfill` and changed a `\raggedleft` into `\raggedright` in `\makelettertitle` and removed the name part and a newline in `\makeletterclosing`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. But I put it just after the last \usepackage(...) line, but the outcome is an error

Comment: @yoannjap I've took your MWE, put this code where I told you, compiled with `pdflatex` and no errors were raised. Maybe your TeX distribution is outdated.